# PHP MYSQL Result is not complete

Tags: php, mysql

This code works unless `$market` returns more then one word.
IE: Colorado would return Pueblo, which works. When it returns "colorado springs", `$market` only echos "colorado" and SID never displays. I am sorry the code might be ugly, but its all I got in a rut.

```
$pickstate = $_POST['state'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ppc WHERE State='" . $pickstate . "'");
      if (!$result) {
        echo("<P>Error performing query: " .
             mysql_error() . "</P>");
       exit();
  }

echo '<form action="" method="POST"><select id="Market" name="Market">';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo ( '<option value= '.$row['Market'].' onclick="this.form.submit();">'.$row['Market'].'</option>' );
}
echo "</select></form>";

$market = $_POST['Market'];
echo "Market = " . $market . "<br />";
$sid = mysql_query("SELECT SID FROM ppc WHERE Market='" . $market . "'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sid)) {
    echo '<p>SID = ' . $row['SID'] . '</p><br />';
}
```

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting. Get rid of that and you'd of (most probably) fixed your code. And `while` you're doing that, I'll get me a drink of water.

Comment: Maybe it pasted wrong up there, editor shows no signs of coding errors, just maybe how I am asking for it.

Comment: SO's syntax highlighting does not lie. Least, it's never lied to me before. ;-)

Comment: Look at the actual HTML code this script creates – then you _should_ see what the problem is.

Comment: Looking at the "source" is also considered an invaluable "tool" in its own right. Some don't even think of using it. The "simple" and "obvious" sometimes don't always seem so, for some. @CBroe

Comment: I edited that error in OP. That was just error in pasting, Sorry.

Output of say Colorado Springs returns:
Market = Colorado

Comment: have you done a var_dump( $_POST['Market'] ); right before assigning it to $market?

Comment: Yes, only shows count of first word. (string(8))

Comment: In the OPTIONS They show up as should, then when I assign that result to $market, only first word shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the quotation marks around the value.  You need to put the quotation marks in just as they are around the onclick.  It shows only the first word because the following words are lost due to the space.  The quotation marks make it include the space and the following words.

```
echo ( '<option value= "'.$row['Market'].'" onclick="this.form.submit();">'.$row['Market'].'</option>' );
```

Comment: That kind of thing is why I wrote php functions for printing out my html, instead of typing each line by hand.  Too easy to miss the closing quotation mark, for example.  I put in an array like `('value'=>$row['market'], 'onclick'=>"this.form.submit()") ` to the function and the function echoes them out with proper quotation marks and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

considering your actual code, you have to change

```
echo "<option value=" . $row['Market'] . " onclick=\"this.form.submit();\" . $row['Market'] . "</option>";
```

to this

```
echo "<option value=" . $row['Market'] . " onclick=\"this.form.submit();\"" . $row['Market'] . "</option>";
```

Also, you may consider writing those lines with readability in mind, something like this:

```
echo ( '<option value= '.$row['Market'].' onclick="this.form.submit();"'.$row['Market'].'</option>' );
```

Combining the different kind of quotes will help. When you have to output double quotes, try surrounding that with single ones.

Comment: That part works just fine. It when I select THAT answer, the next result is only echoed one word. Not the whole string, which is needed for SID.

Comment: although is a good spotting, I'm not missing it, your script does

Comment: Don't worry. So, is the problem fixed or still happen?

Comment: Still happens. that last result only shows first word in string.

This part: echo "Market = " . $market . "<br />";

Comment: You have to put the quotation marks in around the value, just like they are around the onclick.